# Model ID shows as 0 in Laravel transaction

Tags: laravel, transactions

I'm modifying original method in Laravel 5.3 `RegisterController`:

```
protected function create(array $data) {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $user = User::create([
                'id' => $this->generateID(),
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                'active' => 1
    ]);

    if (!$user) {
        DB::rollback();
    }
    DB::commit();

    return $user;

}
```

If I check `dd($user)` inside (or outside) transaction I get `id=0`.

Only if I commit transaction, generated ID is saved to DB, as supposed to be.

What am I missing? Why ID shows as 0 inside a method but as generated ID in DB?

I'd like to use $user-id in:

```
$profile = Profile::create([
        'id' => $user->id,
        'name' => $data['name'],
    ]);
```

inside the same transaction.

Comment: Transaction ends when the execution of the program is over. Execution of the program hold offs if you do a `dd()`. It is same whether you use `dd()` inside the transaction or out side it. when using transactions until the program ended there's no actual output. It is just a set of instructions. That is why you even cannot listen to `db events` while inside the transaction. It's never yet happened until the transaction is committed.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably due to mass assignment, make sure you've whitelisted the fields that correspond:

```
class User extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'email', 'password', 'active'];
}
```

Also, probably best to use a closure and `try/catch` for better error handling:

```
try {
    DB::transaction(function() use($data) {
        $user = User::create([
            'id' => $this->generateID(),
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'active' => 1
        ]);

        Profile::create([
            'id' => $user->id,
            'name' => $data['name']
        ]);    
    });

    DB::commit();
catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    //do something with $e->getMessage();
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm trying to do, but it won't allow me to create Profile because $user->id is 0.
I have all fields whitelisted.

Comment: @Vezlius Are you sure `$this->generateID()` is generating an ID > 0?

Comment: Yes it does. If I run just:

    try {
       DB::transaction(function() use($data) {
           $user = User::create([
                         'id' => $this->generateID(),
                         'email' => $data['email'],
                         'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                         'active' => 1
            ]);
       });
            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
        }

everyting works as intended. That's what confuses me. Trying to figure out how transactions work in Laravel.

Comment: @Vezlius Just do `User::create()->profile()->create([]);` if you have `foreign key constraints` on the `profile.id` column

Comment: Just tested on brand new installation...  If ID is auto incrementing everything works like a charm, even when I do dd($user->id) in transaction it shows corect ID. Obviously messing up with manual IDs in transaction screws up everything.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't generate ID manually. I've just tested it within a transaction and it works:

```
$user = User::create([
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'active' => 1
]);

dd($user->id);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that but in this case I'm trying to avoid auto incrementing IDs. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @Vezlius if you're not using autoincrement feature, just use the same ID for `Profile`, but instead of `id` you should use `user_id` key.

Comment: As I mentioned in my other comment there is something to do with auto vs manual IDs. Appreciate you help, though...